# Android failing to download obb file using unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project for android which is larger than 50MB and so must be split.  I have had working apt splitting for a couple months now.  Starting a few days ago I mad a couple changes which were purely aesthetic.  I uploaded the new build and now(days after the api and obb files were uploaded) I receive an error at the download point on the device "Download failed because the resources could not be found."

I manually added the obb file to the device and it worked, I have tried re uploading the apk and bob files with minor changes and still after a day of waiting see the same errors.

viewing with logcat I see these errors when i try to download

```
I/LicenseChecker(20270): Binding to licensing service.
W/ContextImpl(20270): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 com.unity3d.plugin.downloader.c.j.a:-1 com.unity3d.plugin.downloader.b.s.run:-1 
I/LicenseChecker(20270): Calling checkLicense on service for [my project com]
I/LicenseChecker(20270): Start monitoring timeout.
W/GLSUser (26959): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
I/qtaguid (18936): Failed write_ctrl(u 53) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid (18936): Untagging socket 53 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(18936): untagSocket(53) failed with errno -22
I/ElegantRequestDirector(18936): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
I/ElegantRequestDirector(18936): Retrying request
I/LicenseChecker(20270): Received response.
I/LicenseChecker(20270): Clearing timeout.
```

Its not obvious to me what I did to make obb downloading stop working. I don't know enough about the error messages to pick anything out of it.

What can I do to make it download the bob files again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this here was my solution. It looks like Google made a policy change.

"To test your application's implementation of the manual download procedure, you can publish it to the alpha or beta channel, so it will only be available to authorized testers. If everything works as expected, your application should begin downloading the expansion files as soon as the main activity starts.
Note: Previously you could test an app by uploading an unpublished "draft" version. This functionality is no longer supported; instead, you must publish it to the alpha or beta distribution channel. For more information, see Draft Apps are No Longer Supported."

so now you need to publish your alpha/beta builds before you can download the files.